# Honeypot Positioning

Tags: html, css, spam-prevention

I'm creating a honeypot field in a form exposed at the home page level of a site. The fields go:

```
honeypot
email
name
text area for comment
```

The honeypot is not supposed to show for real users, but should be available for bots to fill out. I used CSS like this:

```
.honey{
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
  }
```

to position the honeypot:

```
<input class="honey" type="text" placeholder="your email" />
```

This isn't working. The input element stays firmly where it was. I've checked to make sure the CSS is the last one loaded, observing the proximity rule and that there is nothing more specific, and can't see any override.

Is there some magic I'm not getting?

Thanks

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/74TW6/.

Comment: This is exactly what I did but because it's inside a set of floated `div`s I believe that's causing it not to want to move.

Comment: This is not really an answer to your CSS question... but I think your approach is not the best from my point of view
CSS display none could be sufficient for some bots but removing the element from the DOM using JS is the best approach because bots usually do not enable JS. 
This package https://packagist.org/packages/dominiquevienne/honeypot is a complete free solution to prevent forms from SPAM without any captcha... Feel free to test: it's quick to install, easy and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `<input>` is inside of another element (like a `<div>`) that has `position: relative;` set, the input will be positioned absolutely but in relation to that element.

Switch to `position: fixed;` because that's relative to viewable screen area.

[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

Comment: So you say switch the enclosing `div` to `position: fixed` and that should solve the problem? I'm wondering if just using a little Javascript would be lower-hanging fruit here.

Comment: No no, just change the `.honey` to `position: fixed;`.  And add a `top: -999em;' while you're at it.

Comment: @SteveRoss Consider a `z-index:-1000;` also. That puts it *under* everything else. When I'm making interactive page widget things, z-index is pretty useful to hide things under a background or something, and there's no risk that a browser interprets a scroll bar is needed.